# Do not automatically add reference when using the Templace producer

Tags: codefluent

I'm doing a CodeFluent Entities project and I use the Template Producer to generate a report that print some statistics about my model.

As I could see, this Producer automatically add two references (CodeFluent.Runtime.dll and CodeFluent.Runtime.Web.dll).
This is a great feature, nevertheless in my case, I don't generate any C# classes so the target project don't really need those references.

How can I disable this behavior ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Template producer inherits from the `CodeDomProducer` (the one that generates the BOM). This allows the template producer to have some useful methods like `AddToGeneratedFiles` that adds the file to Visual Studio target project, or `AddCompilationReferences` which adds references to the target project.

The producer also inherits some configuration options like `Target Project Layout` of type `CodeFluent.Model.Design.TargetProjectLayoutOptions`

```
[Flags]
public enum TargetProjectLayoutOptions
{
    None        = 0x0,

    [Description("Update All")]
    Update = UpdateReferences | UpdateItems,

    [Description("Update References")]
    UpdateReferences = 0x1,

    [Description("Update Items")]
    UpdateItems = 0x2,

    [Description("Do Not Remove Existing Items")]
    DontRemove = 0x4,

    Default     = Update,
}
```

As you can see this allows you to not update project references. So to answer your question, your producer configuration should look like

```
<cf:producer name="Template" typeName="CodeFluent.Producers.CodeDom.TemplateProducer, CodeFluent.Producers.CodeDom">
    <cf:configuration cfx:targetProjectLayout="UpdateItems" [other options] />
</cf:producer>
```

Happy templating :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you really can remove reference from `CodeFluent.Runtime.dll`, since it actually contains the Template engine, see http://blog.codefluententities.com/2013/12/26/exploring-the-codefluent-runtime-the-template-engine/ **in the main project**.

But since the generated code may not reference the `CodeFluent.Runtime.dll` it is not mandatory **in the target project**.

I aggree that it could be usefull to remove the `CodeFluent.Runtime.Web.dll` reference if you do not need it (which actually do not contain very much things, according to http://www.softfluent.com/documentation/).

Comment: The template producer generates code that may not depends on `CodeFluent.Runtime.dll`, so this reference (in the target project) is not mandatory.